# Using the facebook access token with offline_access and javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I have an application that has the offline_access permission, and I obtain the access token via the php sdk and store the access token in my database.

This application works through a website that interacts with facebook, but we do not require the user to be logged in to facebook while using our site. That is, to log in and use our site it is not required to be logged in to facebook. This is the reason we use the offline_access permission.

Now, the question is: how do I use the access token in javascript?

The obvious solution, which is to insert the access token in the web page via a php echo, would be insecure because we currently do not serve pages over https and thus the token travels in plain text. Moreover, if some user left his computer unattended, an attacker could use it and obtain the token by just looking into the site source.

Is there an easy way to securely use this access token? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that [offline access is being deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/). Facebook have blogged about [how to extend expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/), which should answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to securely use the access token with your JavaScript would be to do AJAX requests to PHP scripts. You never, ever want to have that token floating around in browser-land.

Comment: I imagined this is what I would have to do. Thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an AJAX call to a php script (which will use the offline token) from that web page.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you don't want to call the Facebook api from your server with a GET, you can use POST. 
I mean: your page on the server must call the Facebook api so, for instance to write a comment on the user page, you should do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userID/feed?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

but in this way the access_token is displayed on the URL bar of the browser. To hide the parameters, you can use an hidden form that use POST, and submit automatically with javascript

```
<form action="https://graph.facebook.com/userID/feed" name="formNAME" method="POST">               
 <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="XXXX">     
 <input type="hidden" name="description" value="blablabla">   
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">     
 document.formNAME.submit();    
 return;   
</script>
```